# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.client.RxInvokerProvider

Tags: hibernate, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jersey

Im trying to login from a jsp page, using a loginServlet. It redirects to the servlet, but it doesn't make the authentication and throws an error. Here is the code:

JSP file:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">

                    <h2 class="intro-text">Welcome! Login here:</h2>


                    <form class="form-horizontal" action="LoginServlet" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="username">Username:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username" name="un">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

LoginServlet:

```
@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {


public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                       throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {


try
{       

     User user = new User();
     user.setUsername(request.getParameter("un"));
     user.setPassword(request.getParameter("pwd"));

     PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

     // build HTML code
     String htmlRespone = "<html>";
     htmlRespone += "<h2>Your username is: " + user.getUsername() + "<br/>";      
     htmlRespone += "Your password is: " + user.getPassword() + "</h2>";    
     htmlRespone += "</html>";

     writer.println(htmlRespone);

     if (authUser(user))
     {
          System.out.println("exists!");
          HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);       
          session.setAttribute("currentSessionUser",user); 
          response.sendRedirect("home.jsp"); //logged-in page           
     }

     else {
         System.out.println("not!");
            response.sendRedirect("invalidLogin.jsp"); //error page 
     }

} 


catch (Throwable theException)      
{
     System.out.println(theException); 
}
       }

    public boolean authUser(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        User userDB = UserDAO.getUserByUsername(user.getUsername());
        System.out.println(userDB.getUsername()+" "+userDB.getPassword());
        System.out.println(user.getUsername()+" "+user.getPassword());

        if (userDB != null && userDB.getUsername().equals(user.getUsername()) && userDB.getPassword().equals(user.getPassword())) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

getUserByUsername method from UserDAO:

```
public static User getUserByUsername(String username) {

        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        List<User> users = null;

            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery("FROM User WHERE username = :username ");
             query.setParameter("username", username);
            List<User> result = query.list();

            tx.commit();

        return result != null && !result.isEmpty() ? result.get(0) : null;

    }
```

POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.paul.licenta</groupId>
    <artifactId>teachApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>teachApp</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>teachApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.ga</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
               <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
               <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
               <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-m08</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
           <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
          <version>22.0</version>
        </dependency>


    <!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.34</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
       <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.26-b03</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

And here are the errors that I get:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/client/RxInvokerProvider
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getJaxRsProviderInterfaces(Providers.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.<clinit>(Providers.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.modelFor(ComponentBag.java:435)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.lambda$registerModel$5(ComponentBag.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.registerModel(ComponentBag.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.register(ComponentBag.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.register(CommonConfig.java:459)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:447)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:332)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.client.RxInvokerProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    ... 27 more

Aug 06, 2017 11:27:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [Jersey Web Application] in web application [/teachApp] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.client.RxInvokerProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getJaxRsProviderInterfaces(Providers.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.<clinit>(Providers.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.modelFor(ComponentBag.java:435)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.lambda$registerModel$5(ComponentBag.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.registerModel(ComponentBag.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.register(ComponentBag.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.register(CommonConfig.java:459)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:447)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:332)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Aug 06, 2017 11:27:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 06, 2017 11:27:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 06, 2017 11:27:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 9144 ms
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/Session;
```

I tried to add other jars suggested on the internet and some other things that I found here but nothing worked so far. I want it do redirect me to the specified pages after authentication. Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I actually had the same issue.. my solution was based upon the following:

- RxInvokerProvider is in the jaxrs-api with version 2.1 -> you are referencing 2.0
- jersey 2.26 is relying on jaxrs 2.1

After this issue you will  be facing the "Injection" Issue (https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/12e5d8bdf22bcd2676a1032ed69473cf2bbc48c7/docs/src/main/docbook/migration.xml) so you will need the jersey-hk dependency

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.client.RxInvokerProvider` Exception happens during initialization, not during Login. Requests would only be handled after the last lines in the log that you state: `INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]`.

In order to get to the root cause of this exception, run your tomcat in a debugger, set an exception breakpoint on `ClassNotFoundException` and check the actual type of Servlet (there's `GenericServlet.init()` in the stacktrace). That will be the servlet that you'll need to fix. Most likely through adding the required code (or any transitive dependency) to the classpath.

Other than this, this code is wrong on quite a number of levels:

- You're writing output to the response before you redirect: Once text has been sent to the browser, you won't be able to redirect any more, as this requires writing HTTPS headers. When they're already sent, you're out of luck and will generate more exceptions.
- You're not recovering in your transaction from any exceptions (e.g. commit/rollback should be within a finally block) - but at least you're not prone to SQL-injection.
- You're storing clear-text passwords in the database
- You're implementing your own log in when this problem has long been solved, e.g. through the container (read the servlet spec)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I solved the wrong code situations, but still couldnt find something clear about the last bullet point, the container from servlet spec. So Im not sure if I should focus now on solving my servlet problem or learning about containers and use them for authentication

Comment: If I run the same method, authUser(User) from the main class, its working perfectly. Why from within a servlet is causing problems? And if I don't make any request to the DB from servelet, but just compare to some hardcoded user and password, it's also working.I'm really new to servlets, I really struggle with this situation

Comment: authUser does not cause a problem, at least nut in the stacktrace that you posted. Make sure that all required dependencies (jar files) are deployed in WEB-INF/lib to get rid of the CnF-exveption. And accept that the exception (at least the one that you post in your question) happens way before you authenticate.Your authentication problem is either independent or a follow up problem - I can't tell as I don't see the authentication failing.