# FF4J: FeatureStoreHttp throws NoClassDefFoundError : javax/ws/rs/client/RxInvokerProvider

Tags: spring-boot, noclassdeffounderror, ff4j

I have created a feature flag micro-service which holds all the features ( and is connected to oracle db) and I want other applications/micro-services to talk to this feature flag app via Rest API as I don't want them to directly connect to DB. Here is my config.

```java
    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnClass({FF4j.class })
    public class Ff4jConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    
        @Bean
        public FF4j getFF4j() {
            FF4j ff4j = new FF4j();
            ff4j.setFeatureStore(new FeatureStoreHttp("http://localhost:9190/api/ff4j"));
    
            return ff4j;
        }
    }
```

And I get the below error when I invoke ff4j.check("test"). Also, test feature does exists( verified by invoking the REST API - http://localhost:9190/api/ff4j/store/features).

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/client/RxInvokerProvider
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1054) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) [spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665) [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/client/RxInvokerProvider
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getJaxRsProviderInterfaces(Providers.java:117) ~[jersey-common-2.27.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.<clinit>(Providers.java:90) ~[jersey-common-2.27.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.modelFor(ComponentBag.java:518) ~[jersey-common-2.27.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.lambda$registerModel$10(ComponentBag.java:477) ~[jersey-common-2.27.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316) ~[jersey-common-2.27.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298) ~[jersey-common-2.27.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:229) ~[jersey-common-2.27.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.registerModel(ComponentBag.java:469) ~[jersey-common-2.27.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.register(ComponentBag.java:306) ~[jersey-common-2.27.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.register(CommonConfig.java:408) ~[jersey-common-2.27.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.register(ClientConfig.java:235) ~[jersey-client-2.27.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.register(ClientConfig.java:613) ~[jersey-client-2.27.jar:na]
    at org.ff4j.web.api.utils.ClientHttpUtils.buildJerseyClient(ClientHttpUtils.java:60) ~[ff4j-webapi-jersey2x-1.8.9.jar:1.8.9]
    at org.ff4j.web.jersey2.store.FeatureStoreHttp.getJerseyClient(FeatureStoreHttp.java:138) ~[ff4j-webapi-jersey2x-1.8.9.jar:1.8.9]
    at org.ff4j.web.jersey2.store.FeatureStoreHttp.getStore(FeatureStoreHttp.java:151) ~[ff4j-webapi-jersey2x-1.8.9.jar:1.8.9]
    at org.ff4j.web.jersey2.store.FeatureStoreHttp.readAll(FeatureStoreHttp.java:246) ~[ff4j-webapi-jersey2x-1.8.9.jar:1.8.9]
    at org.ff4j.FF4j.getFeatures(FF4j.java:319) ~[ff4j-core-1.8.9.jar:1.8.9]
    at com.sony.spe.spt.rpm.s2f.service.ReleasePackageServiceImpl.getReleasePackages(ReleasePackageServiceImpl.java:447) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sony.spe.spt.rpm.s2f.service.ReleasePackageServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$10394aa0.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sony.spe.spt.rpm.s2f.service.ReleasePackageServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$66167e1f.getReleasePackages(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sony.spe.spt.rpm.s2f.controller.ReleasePackageController.getReleasePackages(ReleasePackageController.java:117) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sony.spe.spt.rpm.s2f.controller.ReleasePackageController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1c52aab0.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sony.spe.spt.rpm.s2f.controller.ReleasePackageController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eef7284f.getReleasePackages(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.client.RxInvokerProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    ... 98 common frames omitted
```

Also, My pom.xml has all the needed dependencies.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ff4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ff4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${ff4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ff4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ff4j-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${ff4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ff4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ff4j-store-springjdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${ff4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ff4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ff4j-webapi-jersey2x</artifactId>
            <version>${ff4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ff4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ff4j-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${ff4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Can someone please suggest if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

The class `FeatureStoreHttp` using a Jersey Client to interact with the API (would be ugraded in ff4j V2 with Feign or WebClient from Spring)

Here your are missing the class `javax.ws.rs.client.RxInvokerProvider`. I would consider adding `jaxrs-api` with version `2.1` in the classpath like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530132/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-ws-rs-client-rxinvokerprovider#45530278)

On a side note:

- spring-boot-starter should be used in the component exposing the REST-API/WEB-CONSOLE not on the client microservices.
- when you define the starter core and aop are already in the classpath

my2c